# Looking for an example of using Lucene.net with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, lucene.net

How do you implement the search capabilities of Lucene.net in asp.net? If possible, please include links or example code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think [mojoPortal](http://www.mojoportal.com/) (ASP.NET CMS) uses Lucene.NET.

Another nice example, [cuyahoga](http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/), makes also use of NHibernate.

You can take a look at their source...

[extra codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/IntroducingLucene.aspx)

Answer (score 23):

There is a excellent blog series here:

1. [Lucene.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20131229052210/http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet)
2. [Introduction to Lucene](https://web.archive.org/web/20131031102410/http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/introduction-to-lucenenet-lucenenet/)
3. [Indexing basics](https://web.archive.org/web/20131031102255/http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/indexing-basics-lucenenet/)
4. [Search basics](https://web.archive.org/web/20131031102439/http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/search-basics-lucenenet/)
5. [Alternatives ( did you mean …)](https://web.archive.org/web/20131231031913/http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/alternatives-did-you-mean-lucenenet/)
6. [Faceted search / Drill down](https://web.archive.org/web/20131031102405/http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/faceted-search-and-drill-down-lucenenet/)
7. [Class reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20131031102400/http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/class-reference-lucenenet/)

I have also found another project called [SimpleLucene](https://web.archive.org/web/20150428223648/http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/?tag=/lucenenet) which you can use to maintain your lucene indexes whenever you need to update or delete a document.

Comment: FYI to those coming across this Q&A: The latest release of Lucene.NET (3.0.3) was back in 2012 and all these links point to articles and resources that go back as far as 2009.

Comment: As of 2/28/2018, there is a beta version of Lucene.Net available that is up to version 4.8.0. You can also find many more supporting packages through NuGet. More info on the latest package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net

Answer (score 8):

Be sure to check out LINQ to Lucene. It's not feature complete, but it does make getting started a lot easier:
http://www.codeplex.com/linqtolucene