# Where I can download example source code of project with using Lucene.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, lucene.net

Where I can download example source code of project with using Lucene.NET for ASP.NET MVC3 web application?

Comment: search on internet I think googling it you will found answer faster then here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already asked and answered: [Looking for an example of using Lucene.net with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339740/looking-for-an-example-of-using-lucene-net-with-asp-net). Corey Trager references his open source project BugTracker.net: http://www.ifdefined.com/blog/post/2009/02/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx .

Comment: Thank you, but I need ready for using simple project, not a part of working code